# Copying response data from rxJs in Angular2/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm using Observable from rxJS in my Angular2 with TypeScript application. I would like to take a copy of the http get response data.

Service:

```js
getSizes(sku: number): Observable<SizeList[]> {
        let api = this.host + this.routes.sizes + sku;
        return this._http.get(api)
                .map((response: Response) => <SizeList[]>response.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Component:

```js
getSizes() {
        this._productService.getSizes(this.productColour)
                .subscribe(
                sizes => this.sizes = sizes,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

How can I take a copy of this.sizes? If I try to take a copy at the end of my components getSizes(), it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to the asynchronous aspect of observables. At the end of the `getSizes` method, the data are there yet. They will be available within the subscribe callback:

```
getSizes() {
    this._productService.getSizes(this.productColour)
            .subscribe(
            sizes => {
              this.sizes = sizes;
              console.log(this.sizes); // <------
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

If you want to return the value from the `getSizes` method, you need to return an observable and let the method caller subscribe on it:

```
getSizes() {
  return this._productService.getSizes(this.productColour)
            .catch(error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}

someOtherMethod() {
  this.getSizes().subscribe(sizes => this.sizes = sizes);
}
```

Comment: You are correct - it's now working by using your first code block example. I didn't know I could have use {} to hold multiple expressions. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is because HTTP requests are made asynchronously in JS/Angular 2, so logic at the end of your `getSizes()` method is probably running before the method `this._productService.getSizes(...)` has finished loading your content.

You should place your logic therefore in the `subscribe()` method like this:

```js
getSizes() {
        this._productService.getSizes(this.productColour)
                .subscribe(
                sizes => { 
                    this.sizes = sizes
                    // more logic here
                },
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

        // code here gets executed before the subscribe() method gets called
}
```